# Consistently getting `None` for the `gdb.Field.name` for a C++ function's parameters

Tags: python, c++, gdb, trace

I'm trying to use `gdb`'s Python API to extract C++'s function parameters' names, and am consistently getting `None` when I query the `name` attribute of function parameters as `gdb.Field` objects.

On a higher level, I need to distinguish between named and anonymous parameters in a function whilst knowing the exact order of the parameters going into the function, so other methods like `info args` or looping over `gdb.Block`s won't work, as they don't include anonymous parameters.

As a simple run, I have the following compiled under debug:

```
// library.h
auto named(int a, int b) -> int;

// library.cpp
auto named(int a, int b) -> int {
  return 0;
}
```

Putting a breakpoint in `gdb` results in

```py
(gdb) python named = gdb.parse_and_eval("named")
(gdb) python print(named.type)
int (int, int)
(gdb) python print(named.type.fields())
[<gdb.Field object at 0x7f79663f29d0>, <gdb.Field object at 0x7f79663f2a10>]
(gdb) python print(named.type.fields()[0].name)
None
(gdb) python print(named.type.fields()[1].name)
None
```

According to https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html#Types-In-Python,

> Function: **Type.fields** *()*
>
> ...
>
> - Function and method types have one field per parameter. The base types of C++ classes are also represented as fields.
>
> ...
>
> Each field is a `gdb.Field` object, with some pre-defined attributes:
>
> ...
>
> `name`
>
> The name of the field, or None for anonymous fields.

I expected `print(named.type.fields()[...].name)` to show `'a'` and `'b'`, rather than `None`, as I've explicitly declared the parameters `a` and `b` in both the definition and the declaration; they aren't prototypes.

Am I missing something about `gdb.Field.name`? Is this attribute only  meaningful for `gdb.Type`s which represent C++ classes/structs?

---

Executed under GDB versions:

- 12.1 (`apt` release)
- 13.0.90.20230102 (weekly snapshot)

Comment: Yes, `gdb.Field.name` is only available for struct and union fields.

Comment: That's unfortunate - the documentation doesn't imply that `gdb.Field.name` is only meant for struct and union fields, so this looks like either a documentation error on the website or a bug in the implementation. This issue occurs in both `gdb 12.1`'s apt distribution release and a fresh installation from gdb's weekly snapshots (version 13.0.90.20230102).